# Cannot run package installation and run serve the application with npm

Tags: vue.js, npm-start, yarn-lock.json

I'm trying to run this sample I found.  This is a solution with .netcore for the backend and Vuejs for the front-end.
I want to start the Vuejs app simply running `npm run serve` got this error:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\VueApp> npm run serve

> vue-argon-dashboard@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then when I try to run `npm i`.
I got the following output:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-argon-dashboard@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^7.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.15
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.4.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is the package.json:

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and after that run `npm i` from the cmd.

Comment: I don't have any node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

There was a lock into the root project directory.  I deleted it and run npm i  --force.  unfortunately, it got more other  different errors

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=       
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Downloads\\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\\Vue\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Downloads\\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\\Vue\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bruno\Downloads\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\vue-argon-dashboard-asp-net-master\Vue\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```